# How to do a bulk delete or replace

Tags: logging, find-and-replace, sdelete

How to do a massive replace or delete (44k+ lines) with the below:

```
Line 238440: <FLTR>
Line 238441: <FLTR>
Line 238442: <FLTR>
Line 238443: <FLTR>
Line 238444: <FLTR>
Line 238445: <FLTR>
Line 238446: <FLTR>
Line 238447: <FLTR>
Line 238448: <FLTR>
Line 238449: <FLTR>
Line 238450: <SQL >
Line 238451: <SQL >
Line 238452: <SQL >
Line 238453: <FLTR>
Line 238454: <FLTR>
Line 238455: <FLTR>
Line 238456: <FLTR>
Line 238457: <FLTR>
Line 238458: <FLTR>
Line 238459: <FLTR>
Line 238460: <FLTR>
Line 238461: <FLTR>
Line 238462: <FLTR>
Line 238463: <FLTR>
Line 238464: <FLTR>
Line 238465: <FLTR>
Line 238466: <FLTR>
Line 238467: <FLTR>
Line 238468: <FLTR>
Line 238469: <FLTR>
Line 238470: <FLTR>
Line 238471: <FLTR>
Line 238472: <FLTR>
Line 238473: <FLTR>
Line 238474: <FLTR>
Line 238475: <FLTR>
Line 238476: <FLTR>
Line 238477: <FLTR>
Line 238478: <FLTR>
Line 238479: <FLTR>
Line 238480: <FLTR>
Line 238481: <FLTR>
Line 238482: <FLTR>
Line 238483: <FLTR>
Line 238484: <FLTR>
Line 238485: <FLTR>
Line 238486: <FLTR>
Line 238487: <FLTR>
Line 238488: <FLTR>
Line 238489: <FLTR>
```

I want to remove the: `Line 238485:` of every line, the thing is that every lines has different number obviously, is there a way to accomplish that?

I just want to have `<FLTR>` or `<API>` or `<SQL>` on my log.

Comment: Your question appears incomplete  Remove all those lines from 1 file?  Remove different linrs from different file? What OS?  How large are files?

Comment: Are you just trying to remove lines 238440 to 238489 from a log/text file?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

- Find: `^Line \d+:`
- Replace: `NOTHING`

Where:

- `^` stands for beginning of line
- `\d+` stands for 1 or more digits.

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/oRQ7WU/1)